# Setting HTML Form Fields in Mechanical Turk (MTurk)

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk

Using Mechanical Turk for the first time. Here is a template of what I am trying to do:

```
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<crowd-form id="form" answer-format="flatten-objects">
  <p id="code"></p>
  <crowd-input name="exit-code" placeholder="paste answer here" required></crowd-input>
</crowd-form>

<script>
// Reference to input .csv form
code_var = ${codes}; 

document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = code_var; 

$("#form").submit( function(eventObj) {
      $("<crowd-input />").attr("type", "hidden")
          .attr("code", code_var)
          .appendTo("#form");
      return true;
  });
</script>
```

The two things I want that are not happening:

1. The codes are not being displayed in the `<p>` tag. If I do `<p id="code">${codes}</p>` then it does work.
2. I want to submit both the code from ${codes} and the exit code on form submission. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

Thank you for any hints or advice!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it.

```
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<crowd-form id="form" answer-format="flatten-objects">
  <p id="code"> ${codes} </p>
  <crowd-input name="exit-code" placeholder="paste answer here" required></crowd-input>
 <crowd-input name="code" style="visibility: hidden;" id="code_form"></crowd-input>
</crowd-form>

<script>
code_var = document.getElementById("code").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("code_form").value = code_var;
</script>
```

Steps:

1. Create invisible  tag.
2. Set the value of the input in a script.